# AngularJS: Good practice to separate controllers / views into sub-directories?

Tags: angularjs

I wondered if anybody if separating there views and controllers into sub directories in AngularJS ?

The reason for this is I am getting quite a lot of views all under my /views and its becoming a difficult to manage.

The same is happening to my controllers.

Does anyone know if its good practice or any issues would present itself?

Or is there an alternative ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check out this excellent article: http://cliffmeyers.com/blog/2013/4/21/code-organization-angularjs-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I  think it's quite OK to create sub-directories for those. But make sure you pick a good logic for separating the views, e.g. that it's not `views/1/*.js` `views/2/*.js`, but instead something like `views/widgets/*.js` `views/top-level/*.js`. I can't think of any problems that arise from this, other than that it's more to configure in build processes, but that's a negligible cost compared to having to manage a mass of files in the same directory.